# How do I center a video inside the player like the YouTube player?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I need to create a player that is (for example) 600px wide and the video is only 300px wide. I want the video to be scaled and centered inside the video area, just like the YouTube player would do if my player was too wide.

This is what I mean (video is centered within control):

[image: Notice video is centered inside the control]

In my attempts to get this to work, the width of the controls for the player seem to be tied to the width of the actual video, so when my video is only 300px wide, the player controls end up being 300px.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could try following less

```
.mejs-container 
{ 
    width: 100% !important; 

    .mejs-mediaelement
    {
        text-align: center !important;

        video { width: 100% !important; }
    }

    .mejs-overlay-play
    {
        position: static !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2/16/2017 Update - I adapted @smiffy6969's answer to use the new classes used in the 3.1.2 version.

```
.mejs__container { width: 100% !important; }
.mejs__mediaelement { text-align: center; }
.mejs__overlay-play { position: static; }
.mejs__poster { width: 100% !important; position: static; }
```

Comment: I had to change all four `__` to `-` and then this worked.